# Rectangle Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Could someone help me through this problem?

This theorem is already proved:
Suppose f is entire and D is the boundary of a rectangle R. Then
$\displaystyle\int_{D} f(z)\, dz$

Now he must prove this directly from the theorem: 
given any rectangle with vertices (a, c), (b, c), (b, d) and (a, d), parameterize the boundary D and verify directly that
$\displaystyle\int_{D}\, dz=$$\displaystyle\int_{D}z\, dz=0$

Comment: What theorem is proved?

Comment: This:Suppose f is entire and D is the boundary of a rectangle R. Then

Comment: You should have an $=0$ after the integral.

Comment: I think I'm missing the point. The functions $z \mapsto 1$ and $z \mapsto z$ are entire so the result follows trivially from the theorem. However, the statement of the problem talks about 'parameterizing the boundary'...

Comment: @copper.hat: Yes, I thought of that after I posted my answer.

Comment: I agree with copper.hat: the point of this exercise would be to verify the theorem *by hand*, not by applying the theorem. That is: parameterize $D$ and calculate the two integrals and check that they are both zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(z)=z-1$ is entire, so $\int_D f(z)dz=0$. This translates to $\int_D dz=\int_D z dz$.

Comment: I made a correction in the statement (∫Ddz=∫Dzdz=0), it still validates your proposal?

Comment: Apply the same result for $f(z)=z+1$.